# Unity Text Option Not Appearing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a 3D game and I need to add some texts but I don't have the unity text option in UI in Hierarchy, I have other options like TextMeshPro but not Text itself

Answer (score 2):

Create a Empty Gameobject , and add Compoent by you self.

[image]